# Exception in thread "main" line 37

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at WeatherAnalysis.main(WeatherAnalysis.java:37)" Im not sure what is wrong at line 37, date[CurrentLine][0] = (int)fullDate % 100;. Trying to use .txt file to output weather patterns from 1941 to 2013.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeatherAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {

        int NumberOfDays = 0;
        String station;
        File f = new File("PortlandWeatherCut.txt"); //Import text file.
        Scanner input= new Scanner(f);
        input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {  //Assign number of days to be         
            NumberOfDays++;
            input.nextLine();
        }

        double[][] date = new double[NumberOfDays][3];
        double[] prcp = new double[NumberOfDays];
        double[] snow = new double[NumberOfDays];
        double[] snwd = new double[NumberOfDays];
        double[] tmax = new double[NumberOfDays];
        double[] tmin = new double[NumberOfDays];
        int CurrentLine = 0;
        double fullDate = 0.0;

        File g = new File("PortlandWeather.txt"); //Import text file.
        Scanner weather= new Scanner(g);
        weather.nextLine(); weather.nextLine();

        while(weather.hasNextLine()) { //variables and converts to inches.
        station = weather.next();
        fullDate = weather.nextDouble();
        date[CurrentLine][0] = (int)fullDate % 100;
        date[CurrentLine][1] = ((int)fullDate % 10000) / 100;
        date[CurrentLine][2] = (int)fullDate / 10000;
        prcp[CurrentLine] = weather.nextDouble()* .00393701;
        snow[CurrentLine] = weather.nextDouble()* 0.0393701;
        snwd[CurrentLine] = weather.nextDouble()* 0.0393701;
        tmax[CurrentLine] = (weather.nextDouble() / 10.0) * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
        tmin[CurrentLine] = (weather.nextDouble() / 10.0) * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
        CurrentLine++;
        weather.nextLine();
    }
    int indexPoint = 0;
    int nextPoint = 1;
    int endPoint = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x < date.length; x++){ 
        //loop that calculates array section to be averaged,
        //uses a method to average them, then prints a table
        do {
                nextPoint++;
                endPoint++;
        }
        while(((int)date[nextPoint - 1][02] / 10) == ((int)date[nextPoint][1] / 10)); 
        if ( nextPoint < date.length) {
        System.out.printf("%4.0f's Average Max Temp = %4.1f\tAverage Min   Temp = %4.1f\n",
                 date[indexPoint][02],arrayAvg(tmax, indexPoint, endPoint),
                    arrayAvg(tmin, indexPoint, endPoint));
            indexPoint = nextPoint;
            } else 
                System.out.println();

        }
    }
    public static double arrayAvg(double a[], int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        //Averages the values between the entered parameters and returns it.
        double sum = 0;
        double divisor = 0;
        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++){
            if (a[i] == 393.6616299) {
                divisor++;
            } else {
                sum += a[i];
                divisor++;
            }   
        }
        double average = sum / divisor;
        return average;
    }
}
```

Comment: `PortlandWeather.txt` has more lines than `PortlandWeatherCut.txt`, perhaps?

Comment: it does have more lines

Comment: What is the content of PortlandWeatherCut.txt?

Comment: You allocate an array with the same number of rows as the first file, then try to read rows from the second, larger file into that array. Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your issue is at line 37. I think that is the

```
date[currentline][0] = (int)fullDate%100
```

Inside of your while loop. The loop continues above the NumberOFdAYS that the date 2-dimensional array was created with, therefore it throws out of bout.

My first advise is to break down this monster function into smaller function (Look up Single Responsibility principle).

My second advise is to do TDD (Test driven development)

But if you want a quick and dirty debug, do the following at the beginning of your while loop:

```
System.out.printf("Current line = %d, does weather has next line? = %b", CurrentLine, weather.hasNextLine)
```

This will show you all the values of currentLine before the exception and shows the value of your boolean.